# listview XML id issue

Tags: java, android

I've just started a new class, and have laid the XML out as I have done with a couple of other classes with no problems but I'm now getting a really weird resource error with this class.

I have an XML layout called 'edit' which contains an edittext, a button and a listview. for some reason when I enter my listview refence in my class I get the error of 'cannot be resolved' I really don't understand this as it is clearly defined in the XML.

Currently the id is referenced as so:

```
android:id="@android:id/listEdit"
```

This ID refrence seems to make the listview disappear all together in the layout giving me the following error:

```
NOTE: This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause  rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.

Couldn't resolve resource @android:id/listEdit
```

Heres my 'edit' XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txteditSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type A Name To Edit;"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputNameEdit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearchEdit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/listEdit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listEdit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my edit class:

```
package com.example.flybase2;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class edit extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {


Button editSearch;
EditText nameEdit;
ListView editList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.edit);

            // ERROR: Error on the 'listEdit'
    editList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.listEdit);

    DBHandler DBedit = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

    DBedit.open();
    Cursor cursor = DBedit.getData();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    String [] from = new String [] {DBedit.KEY_NAME, DBedit.KEY_TEL,  DBedit.KEY_EMAIL, DBedit.KEY_COMMENTS};
    int [] to = new int [] {R.id.txtNameSet, R.id.txtContactSet,  R.id.txtEmailSet, R.id.txtCommentSet};

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,    R.layout.searchagain, cursor, from, to);
    editList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);


    editSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchName); 
    nameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName); 


    editSearch.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View clickedSearchButton) {

String searchedName = nameEdit.getText().toString();

editList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

DBHandler DBsearchRef = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

DBHandler search = new DBHandler(this, null, null);

search.open();
Cursor cursor = search.searchOnName(searchedName);

startManagingCursor(cursor);

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
String [] from = new String [] {DBsearchRef.KEY_NAME, DBsearchRef.KEY_TEL,  DBsearchRef.KEY_EMAIL, DBsearchRef.KEY_COMMENTS};
int [] to = new int [] {R.id.txtEditNameSet, R.id.txtEditNumSet,    R.id.txtEditEmailSet, R.id.txtEditCommentsSet};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.setedit, cursor, from, to);
editList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);



}

}
```

Can anyone see why this is happening as its driving me crazy!

Comment: android:id/listEdit does not exist. you need to use android:id/list if you are using a listActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ListActivity` you should use `android:id="@android:id/list"` as id for `ListView`.

Then you can reference `ListView` using `getListView()` method so you do not have to keep reference yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this below line

```
  android:id="@+id/listEdit"
```

instead of this

```
android:id="@android:id/listEdit"
```

Answer (score 0):

the message is exactly that it means, there's no id:

```
 android:id="@android:id/listEdit"
```

on the android framework, what you want to use is:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```